# Integration test only works with a Thread.Sleep

Tags: c#, integration-testing, race-condition

We currently have an integration test that tests a front-end api call. The call is async therefore we force it until the call is ready to compare the result with what we expect.

However, the problem is that the code contains also an another async call which is not awaited. So we have nested async calls. This also has the cause that the test sometimes succeeds and sometimes it fails (race condition).

For now we have fixed the issue by added a Thread.Sleep (10000) to the code. However, this is not a good solution.

The code likes like this:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Integration_Test_Example()
    {
        // Arrange
        ...

        // Act
        var request = CreateRequest(@"testfile.xml");
        var task = target.SendMessage(request);

        Thread.Sleep(10000); // dirty fix

        task.Wait();

        // Assert
        ...
    }
```

Does anyone have advice on how we can best solve this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly `SendMessage` returns task, so you should be able to await it before moving on with your test.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task Integration_Test_Example()
{
    var request = CreateRequest(@"testfile.xml");
    var result = await target.SendMessage(request);
}
```

Comment: The other async call is not awaited, therefore this doesn't work.

Comment: Your `SendMessage` returns task, so why can't you do `await` inside `SendMessage`? Can you show us `SendMessage` code?

Comment: @LeviSteenbergen But isn't that saying your implementation is broken and you are lucky your test actually fails sometimes? In production, you'd have that race, too, wouldn't you?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the test to be awaitable

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Integration_Test_Example()
    {
        // Arrange
        ...

        // Act
        var request = CreateRequest(@"testfile.xml");
        await target.SendMessage(request);

        // Assert
        ...
    }
```

Comment: The other async call is not awaited, therefore this doesn't work

Comment: @LeviSteenbergen Then please give a **complete** example!